# ElasticSearch Polish Analysis Tokenizer not found

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, stemming, polish

I have dockerized ElasticSearch 1.4.2 and I'm trying to make Polish Stemmer work (https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-analysis-stempel). After a few issues with installation I have finally done that, but the ElasticSearch still cannot see the Analyzer when I'm trying to Analyze a single text:

`curl -XGET localhost:9200/_cat/plugins?v
name      component        version type url 
Elsie-Dee analysis-stempel 2.4.1   j`

`curl -XGET localhost:9200/_analyze?analyzer=polish -d 'medyczne'
{"error":"ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[failed to find analyzer [polish]]","status":400}`

I wanted to test how it works so I believe I do not have to create a mapping to analyze particular text, do I?

I have checked `elasticsearch.log` and there's nothing about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been playing with polish analyzer not so long time ago.
On my machine querying localhost:9200/_plugins give me list of

```
Richard Rider analysis-stempel   2.4.0 j  
Richard Rider mapper-attachments 2.4.0 j
```

You don't need to create index, first you can check how it works by querying _analyze endpoint:

```
GET /_analyze
{
  "analyzer" : "polish",
  "text" : "polskimi"
}
```

It returns valid tokens for me ("polski").
BTW There is an official docker image for latest 5.X version. On my local PC (as you can see) I have 2.4.0

Comment: Yeah, but I could not install `stempel` for 2.4.0. There were some errors.

Also, how did you get `mapper-attachments` ?

Comment: From the internet :) I was installing the usual way `bin\plugin install` as far as I remember. What errors do you have?

Comment: I have built fresh ES from Docker 2.4.0, then:

```bin/plugin install analysis-stempel
```

It says it's done.

Restarted elasticsearch via `service elasticsearch restart`. After that I've done:

```curl -XGET localhost:9200/_analyze -d '{ "analyzer": "polish", "text": "polskimi"}'
```

And the response is:

```{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"remote_transport_exception","reason":"[Mys-Tech][172.17.0.2:9300][indices:admin/analyze[s]]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"failed to find analyzer [polish]"},"status":400}
```

Comment: Just a thought: Maybe I'm shutting down it incorrectly?

I've got compose running in one terminal window, on the second I'm sshing to /bin/bash and then trying 
`service elasticsearch stop` but even after that I can curl localhost:9200 and stilll got the answer.

Comment: @UP: 
EDIT:

I have installed ES on the machine without docker and it helped. So probably that's the issue. Any ideas how to stop and start elasticsearch while using `docker-compose`? Not my area of expertise tho, still learning

Comment: Maybe indeed, you were querying not the same instance of ES? Maybe that's issue of many nodes?

Comment: Might be. Anyway when I put `service elasticsearch stop` and `start` into Dockerfile it started to work. So thanks for above!